# What are the core differences in platform support between TideSDK and TideKit?

Tags: tidesdk, tidekit

I have a project I have coded using TideSDK. What is the difference in purpose and support for platforms between TideSDK and TideKit?

Comment: Sorry this was supposed to be a question and answer. Let me edit and correct this.

Comment: This is not a StackOverflow question, even if you edit it to be a question/answer. It's a post for the product documentation instead. Please do not use StackOverflow to promote your product or project; that's not what this site is designed to do.

Comment: There are technical differences between the two pieces of software, this is not promotion but valid question I am answering for our users to assist them in assessing differences in platform support.

Comment: Provide information for your users on your project documentation site where it belongs.

Comment: @KenWhite We have had this question come up in discussion on twitter and it this is about answering differences. Of course our documentation will spell what platforms we support but it will not clarify differences with other similarly named software which is what this question entails. I would appreciate if you could keep this in mind for those folks that will benefit from the answer i will prepare.

Comment: If you're getting questions on twitter about it, it's clear your documentation isn't sufficient, and you should **edit your documentation** to provide that information. SO is not intended to be your product documentation supplementary site. IMO, this question should probably be flagged as spam, because it's intended for nothing but product promotion instead of technical merit to future users of this site.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion on this but we have folks that will be transitioning between the two types of software. We are making this point so that folks use either TideSDK or TideKit have a clearer understanding of the technical differences between these. We'd like this question here to help them. Hope that clarifies this finally.

Comment: Sorry, but I still think this belongs on your own documentation pages. Voting to close. IMO, this question appears to be off-topic because it is a product documentation post that should be on the product site (perhaps as part of a FAQ section).

Comment: Appropriate questions on this site may be asked and answered on software tools commonly used by programmers without a source code fragment. This is a question about software tools. It is being asked and answered by a core developer of these tools to assist users of software under both tags indicated.

Comment: I have evolved the question further. I have been clear about the intent of the question and answer. The question is asked here since this is the principal source of questions and answers for TideSDK and for emerging TideKit platform.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are key technical differences between [TideKit](http://tidekit.com) and [TideSDK](http://tidesdk.org) despite the similar sounding name. TideKit is an application development *platform* for desktop, web and mobile whereas TideSDK is a desktop SDK (Software Development Kit).

TideKit was developed by the same core developers that developed TideSDK. They went on to found [CoastalForge](http://coastalforge.com) to create TideKit with the vision of creating for all screens and devices. From the source code of a single project, an app can be built and packaged for each device, bridging each language, its user interfaces and capabilities. As of this date, TideKit has been in development and is due to be released. Development can be following on Twitter at https://twitter.com/tidekit

TideKit is not a single tool, piece of software, UI or SDK (Software Development Kit). It is a central hub for app development. TideKit combines remote software together with local software that you use on your system. Developers write code using their favourite text editor and interact with TideKit through a CLI (Command Line Interface) or through interaction with the TideKit app.

[image]

TideKit provides more than a single approach to development. In its simplest form it can be used in a similar way to TideSDK for app development, but it has much greater capabilities. TideKit was designed to create ubiquitous apps for all screens and devices at one time. This is accomplished using CommonJS. You write your project code once, then build and package it for virtually all operating systems and devices for mobile, web and desktop. Development using TideKit is fully unified for client, server, desktop, mobile or web.

The primary advantages are access (ie developing in JavaScript instead of the core languages to get native features), development speed (everything can be created at a fraction of the time compared to developing for one platform), lower development cost, and more reach (able to create for all platforms to monetize everywhere with a single effort).

TideKit is for the whole of app development, therefore it differs greatly in platform support that is summarized below. Despite these differences, a TideSDK project may be migrated to TideKit with small changes in your code.

**TideKit**

- Windows XP
- Windows Vista
- Windows 7
- Windows 8
- OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard
- OSX 10.7 Lion
- OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion
- OSX 10.9 Mavericks
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Ubuntu 12.11
- Ubuntu 13.04
- iOS 6
- iOS 7
- Android
- Ubuntu Server
- RedHat
- CentOS

**TideSDK**

- Windows XP
- Windows Vista
- Windows 7
- Windows 8
- OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard
- OSX 10.7 Lion
- OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Ubuntu 12.11